# Has anyone in the world reached the 2048th tile in 2048 3×3 game? Is it even possible?

Tags: 2048

I barely managed to reach 64 in the 3×3 board when it was game over. 4×4 is still doable, but 3×3 is pretty impossible to me.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

That's mathematically not possible. Let's assume that you are very-very lucky and you only get number 4 tiles as the new ones.

That is 2^2, and we have 9 tiles, each of them twice as big as the previous one. That adds up to:

> 2^2, 2^3, 2^4, 2^5, 2^6, 2^7, 2^8, 2^9, 2^10

As you can see, 2^10 is the maximum possible we can have, which is just a 1024

So to answer your question: it's not possible to reach 2048 tile in a 3x3 version of the game(assuming that the rules are the same as with 4x4: 1 new tile after each move, which is either 2 or 4)

Comment: Stupid question : does the whole sequence need to be present?

Comment: @EricDuminil, not a stupid question. To reach a 2048, at one point the sum of all pieces must have been 2044 or 2046, i.e. binary 1111111110 or 1111111100. The only way to get this with at most 9 pieces is to have the pieces which are shown in the answer. Unfortunately, having these 9 pieces means that the position is locked.

Comment: @EricDuminil to put it another way, to get the next tile, you must merge two copies of the previous tile, right? so if you're missing a tile, there will be only one copy of some tile after the previous merge (= no next merge)

Comment: this is not in-and-of-itself a proof that 2048 is entirely impossible. This demonstrates that with enough luck, it would be possible to get all the tiles from "4" to "1024" present on the screen at once. That isn't an immediate lock (the lock is if a tile needs to be added and can't, but as stated at the top, we assume the "4" tile was just added). If the layout is correct (e.g. zigzag), it would indeed be possible to combine every tile in sequence to achieve a 2048 tile, with new tiles filling in the spaces as they form.

Comment: @Dave incorrect, note that the sequence given is 9 tiles long - it is game over, there is *no* way to free up a space to let the other 4 spawn in

Comment: ah because it needs a second 4 to merge with, yes. Quite right

Comment: worth noting though that you don't need to be "lucky", you just need decent luck, *and* have the final tile that spawns in be a 4, to get the above sequence

Comment: not quite true; you need to be incredibly lucky in the _locations_ where tiles spawn to be able to repeatedly collapse the chains in the right order as the grid gets so full. So much so that I would say it would only be possible to reach this point with an adapted version of the game which reliably spawns tiles in favourable positions (and even with perfect spawning it may actually be impossible to reach even this point due to how movement repositions multiple tiles at once)

Comment: @Dave: In order to reach a situation with two 1024 tiles, one must have been in a situation with one 1024 tile and two 512 tiles.  In order to reach such a situation, one must have previously been in a situation with either four three 512 tiles and two 256 tiles, or else one 1024 tile, one 512 tile and two 256 tiles.  In other words, a situation with two 256 tiles and at least two higher tiles.  To reach that, one must have been in a situation with two 128 tiles and at least three higher tiles, two 64 tiles and four higher tiles; also 2x32 and five; 2x16 and six; 2x8 and seven; 2x4 and eight.

Comment: Put differently, if there are `n` points on the board, and `n = 2^i - 1`, there must be at least `i` tiles on the board. This can be proved through induction, but it's also easy to see for, e.g., `n=7` and `i=3`.